# Replace special characters with corresponding english letter

Tags: java, unicode, fuzzy-search, unicode-normalization, phonetics

Looking for an implementation or library (ideally in Java), that will transform **Unicode** text such as below, to the corresponding **ASCII** English characters:

> ʀᴇɢɪꜱᴛʀᴀᴛɪᴏɴ

The below should be converted to:

> REGISTRATION

Note however that are other possible characters to be converted such as in "cσdє".

The final goal is to do a **phenetic/fuzzy match**, however I believe that becomes easy once the characters are actual ASCII english.

Comment: Well, the big question is that you need to know what to map to what other character. Actually doing the replacing is a matter of just calling `replaceAll`.

Comment: @Ben I have a sample of about 60 strings, and I could work on implementing a character mapping covering the whole 'known' set. However since there are so many characters I am checking if anyone has put work on this already.

Comment: There's a relevant post here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128286/list-of-visually-similar-characters-for-detecting-spoofing-and-social-engineeri

Answer (score 1):

It turns out they are called Homoglyphs, so we're trying to protect against Homoglyph/Homograph attacks.

I have found this library, [*Homoglyph Detection*](https://codebox.net/pages/homoglyph-detection), to be a good starting point for a solution; they provide good mappings, however incomplete to really stop spam.

It would be nice to have such unicode-to-latin mapping files being shared and completed by the community.